# Smart contract copying code beyong code length

Tags: contract-design, contract-debugging, bytecode

I've seen a couple smart contracts (eg the contract decompiled in [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/77490/67894)) use this pattern:
`Code[Code.Length:Code.Length+x]`

This surprised me because I would expect Code.Length to mark the end of Code. What would the result of this expression be and what could the purpose be for using this pattern?